# How to shrink an ext4 /home partition without using a LiveCD and losing data?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, 64-bit, ext4

I need to shrink an ext4 `/home` partition (`/dev/sda9`) to make space for something else.

I would prefer avoid live CDs (boot troubles with new EFI and. I don't have a CD/USB in hand in the office).

I can boot as root directly to command line so I can unmount `/home` but then, for some reasons, I can't use the GUI even for the root user, so I can't use GParted.

Is there a terminal command to resize an unmounted ext4 partition without losing data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment out the corresponding line in `/etc/fstab`, reboot into recovery mode and make shure that `/home/$your_user` exists and has the correct permissions (`mkdir -p /home/$your_user && chown $your_user:$your_user /home/$your_user`). Reboot and you can use the GUI to shrink the partition.

---

The terminal command for EXT filesystems is `resize2fs`, depending on the partition table you have to use different tools to resize the partition (e.g. `fdisk` or `gdisk`), but I would recommend using the GUI.

Comment: yes, at the ned I used gparted. Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't tought to just comment /home in fstab..